# Remove html elements added dynamically with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom-manipulation

In my html page, I have a select with some options.
When selecting an option, an ajax call is fired passing the option's value to a php script, which returns an html fragment (another select) with a certain id that is appended to the page.

When the user selects another option from the first select, the event is fired again, the ajax call is executed and another html fragment (with the same id) gets appended to the page.

I want that, if the event is fired a second time, the appended element is removed form the page before appending the new one.

At the moment I'm using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_serie").change(function() { //#id_serie is the if of the first select
        if ($("#id_subserie_label")) { //#id_subserie_label is the id of the html element returned by the ajax call
            console.log("Removing");
            $("#id_subserie_label").empty().remove();
        }
        var url = 'myscript.php';
        var id_s = $(this).val();
        $.post(url, {id_serie: id_s}, function(data) {
            $("#id_serie").parent().after(data);
        });
    });
});
```

This is not working though, the html element returned by the second ajax call is appended after the element returned from the first call (because the element with id #id_subserie_label is not in the page when the script is loaded?).

How can I achieve what I need?

Comment: The reason Matt Ball's answer is right, is that the jQuery $() function will always return a jQuery object whether or not it is able to find the elements you're looking for. The .length property tells you how many elements it found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're very close.**

Just change `if ($("#id_subserie_label"))` to `if ($("#id_subserie_label").length)`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_serie").change(function() {
        if ($("#id_subserie_label").length) { // <=== change this line
            console.log("Removing");
            $("#id_subserie_label").empty().remove();
        }
        var url = 'myscript.php';
        var id_s = $(this).val();
        $.post(url, {id_serie: id_s}, function(data) {
            $("#id_serie").parent().after(data);
        });
    });
});
```

See [The jQuery FAQ: How do I test whether an element exists?](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_test_whether_an_element_exists.3F).

---

This is because, as [Ivo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170224/ivo-wetzel) points out:

> `$("#id_subserie_label")` is an object, and objects always evaluate to true.

---

As per [Andy E's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e) comment, you can simplify your code to this, if you don't need the `console.log()` call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_serie").change(function() {
        $("#id_subserie_label").empty().remove();
        var url = 'myscript.php';
        var id_s = $(this).val();
        $.post(url, {id_serie: id_s}, function(data) {
            $("#id_serie").parent().after(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: For explanation: `$("#id_subserie_label")` is an object, an objects always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: The `if` statement is only really needed for that `console.log` call.  Other than that, it's not needed at all as jQuery will only empty/remove the elements in the matched set if the length is greater than 0.

Comment: Stuff like this makes me wonder why the ECMAScript backend function `ToBoolean` was never exposed like `toString` and `valueOf`.  `Object.prototype.toBoolean` would be great for exactly this situation and many others.

Comment: Thank you Matt, I added .length to my code and everything worked fine, and I learned something new about jQuery!